# SqlAlchemy: Money amount precision based on currency

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have a model with two fields `amount` and `currency`. The `amount` field is currently a custom type, which handles `Decimal` values but persists them as integers. The `Decimal` type looks something like this:

```py
class Decimal(sa.types.TypeDecorator):
    impl = sa.types.INTEGER

    # This was computed by `math.log(2 ** 64, 10) - 1`. This is the maximum power of 10 we can
    # store in a 64 bit integer.
    MAX_POW = 18

    def __init__(self, digits, decimal_places):
        if digits < 0 or decimal_places < 0:
            raise ValueError("Can't have negative amounts of digits or decimal places")
        if (digits + decimal_places) > self.MAX_POW:
            raise ValueError("We can't store such precision")
        super().__init__()
        self.digits = digits
        self.decimal_places = decimal_places

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        if value is None:
            return value

        if isinstance(value, int):
            value = decimal.Decimal(value)
        if not isinstance(value, decimal.Decimal):
            raise TypeError("Values are expected to be python Decimals")

        if count_integer_part(value) > self.digits:
            raise ValueError("Can't store that many digits before the decimal point")
        if count_fractional_part(value) > self.decimal_places:
            raise ValueError("Can't store that many digits after the decimal point")

        integer = value.scaleb(self.decimal_places)
        assert integer % 1 == 0, "Integer should not have digits after the decimal point"
        return int(integer)

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        if value is None:
            return value
        return decimal.Decimal(value).scaleb(-self.decimal_places)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Decimal({self.digits}, {self.decimal_places})"
```

Currently all fields holding money values use the parametrised `MoneyAmount`

```
MoneyAmount = functools.partial(Decimal, digits=16, decimal_places=2)
```

I now want to support currencies with **more than two** decimal places. The actual number of decimal places should be calculated from the `currency` field with an appropriate lookup-table. I have been trying to use a [hybrid_property](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#module-sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid), but have some trouble defining the `hybrid_property.expression` (or `hybrid_property.comparator`), I would have to define the same lookup in a SQL expression.

```py
decimal_places: dict[str, int] = {
    "BHD": 3,
}

class Table(declarative_base()):
    __tablename__ = "test"

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        amount = kwargs.pop("amount", None)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        if amount is not None:
            self.amount = amount

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    _amount = sa.Column(sa.Integer, nullable=False, default=0)
    currency = sa.Column(sa.String(3), nullable=False, default="")

    @hybrid_property
    def amount(self):
        places = decimal_places.get(self.currency, 2)
        return Decimal(self._amount).scaleb(-places)

    @amount.setter
    def amount(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, Decimal):
            value = Decimal(value)
        places = decimal_places.get(self.currency, 2)
        integer = value.scaleb(places)
        self._amount = int(integer)

    @amount.expression
    def amount(cls):
        # TODO: What to do here?
```

I found [this](https://techspot.zzzeek.org/2011/10/29/value-agnostic-types-part-ii/) old blog post that is somehow dealing with the same problem domain, but uses numeric/float types for storing data.
Do you guys have any suggestion on how to approach this problem?

Comment: Answered on GitHub [here](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/7124).

Answer (score 1):

`@amount.expression` could be made working as per below:

```
@amount.expression
def amount(cls):
    sub_queries = [
        select(literal(k).label("currency"), literal(v).label("decimal_places"))
        for k, v in decimal_places.items()
    ]
    cte = union_all(*sub_queries).cte("cte")

    return (
        cls._amount
        * sa.func.power(
            10,
            -sa.func.coalesce(
                select(cte.c.decimal_places)
                .filter(cte.c.currency == cls.currency)
                .scalar_subquery(),
                2,
            ),
        )
    ).label("amount")
```

*Please note that for this to work on `sqlite` (as you indicated in the tags of the question), the `power` function needs to be included in the build. Alternatively, you can use python implementation for testing:*

```
# sqlite:only: create power function
if engine.name == "sqlite":
    session.connection().connection.connection.create_function(
        "power", 2, lambda x, y: x ** y
    )
```

*Further note: for postgresql i would use `values/cte` instead of `union_all`, but `sqlite` does not work with sub-queries using it.*

---

I think this answers your question, but this is not the full solution to the higher level task you aim to solve, as returned values will not have the same [quantum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.same_quantum).